# Automate installation of binary in linux

Tags: linux, binary, automation, installation, provisioning

I have a Bourne-Again shell script text executable named `engine.bin` that I want to install.

If I install the executable manually `./engine.bin` I get a screen with the EULA I have to accept (by pushing space), then accept it by writing `yes` and then enter the installation path by typing `/usr/local/engine`.

Now I want to do the installation automatically through provisioning scripts **without manual interaction**. Is there a way to do this? I do not know if the installer accepts any parameters, unfortunately the thing is undocumented.

Comment: you can use the `expect` package if it is already installed within the environment. Let me know if it isn't and then ill think of some other ways you can do this.

Comment: I'm able to install expect and got it working.

Comment: great to hear! I would have made an answer out of it but didn't have the time :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion of bill-agee and jgr208 I wrote the following which is working for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn /tmp/engine.bin
expect {
   -gl "*Press SPACE or PAGE DOWN key to continue, U or PAGE UP key to scroll back*" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
   -gl "*yes/no*"
}
send -- "yes\r" 
expect -gl "*press ENTER to accept the default*"
send -- "/tmp/tce\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

If the executable allows you to spam input at it without waiting for each separate prompt to appear, you might be able to accomplish this with bash.

For example, this script will run `program_that_takes_several_lines_of_input.py` and send it four lines of input - three with text and one blank line:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux

./program_that_takes_several_lines_of_input.py <<EOD
first line
one enter keypress later

yet another line of input after the empty line above
EOD
```

If you need to stop and wait for each prompt to appear, the cram Python package may be a good fit for this scenario - I find it useful for tasks like this where you only need to send a few lines of input, but each line of input is different.

See:

https://bitheap.org/cram/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cram

Expect would also work, but I find that I reach working solutions a bit faster when using cram than with Expect.

pexpect is a great choice as well! See:

https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

Comment: The bash solution does not work, but I got it working with expect. I'll write the answer below. Thank you.